# get method won't "get" static array correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, get

So i have this code that is supposed to return, from a class, a private variable declared as a static array, but, for instance, if i were to print said get it will result in 1 blank, the code will explain. Suppose:

```
class A {
private:
char array[100];

//...

public:
//...

char get_array() const {return array(100);}
};
```

Now I understand that it DOES return something, and that is the 100th position. I also tried to do `return *array;` and since array are not given to functions, instead pointers are provided, it would just give me the first letter in said array. Since I want the entire array to be returned, what should I do? Thanks

Comment: `char* get_array() const {return array; }`
P.S. Get a *good* book. Much of what you say indicates that there is a lot of things to be understood yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type of your function is "char", which is one character. With "array(100)" you select the corresponding element.
Use char* as return value (like Michael Chourdakis said), this gives you the pointer to the array.